# How to set the form to be sent when textarea have minlength 20 characters?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have problem, I want to sent form when textarea have minlength 20 char, but my code don't working.
All the time when pressed button returns false
I want that code dont send when window load and textarea length equals 0

```
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
         const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

         f = false;
         t = true;




         const blockBtn = (b) => {
             btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
                 console.log(b);
                 e.returnValue = b;
                 //  console.log(e.returnValue);

             });
         }

         const textArea = function (event) {
             const length = this.value.length;
             console.log(length);
             if (length < 20 || length == null) {
                 blockBtn(f);
             } else {
                 console.log('dziala')
                 blockBtn(t);
             };
         }

         const textAreaWindow = () => {
             const messageValueLength = message.value.length;
             if (messageValueLength == 0) {
                 blockBtn(f);
             }
         }

         message.addEventListener('input', textArea);
         window.addEventListener('load', textAreaWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this:

```
 f = false;
 t = true;
```

Is redundant (and bad), just pass true/false.

Secondly, you never remove the old listeners, so by the time you've typed 20 characters your button is firing 20 events. This is also bad.

Rather than update the listener every time there's a change, simply get the length of the textbox when you click the button.